# Calculate the sum of dices based on target accurately

Tags: java, list, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I am trying, to sum up score for a little dice game I made. The dice has the following values: `1-6`, the player can select `target`, `LOW = n < 4`, **1,2,3**. The rest of the targets, `4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11` and `12`.

When a throw is done, sum up the total sum of the dices, based on `target` value. What this means, is, if **LOW** is select, then everything below **4**, is summed up. Otherwise, the process, must **sum** each dice till it reaches the target **sum**, and continue.
If, a throw is done, and I selected `6` as target, and get the following set: `{1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6}`. We have a `6`, `5+1=6`, and `4+2=6`, we are left with `1` which is not counted.

**Constraints:**

- *1-6* dice values.
- Everything (Target) below *4*, is summed up.
- Everything (Target) selecting between *4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, & 1*2, is processed differently.
- 6 dices, can produces any number between `1-6`. This means, `[6,6,6,6,6,6]`, or `[1,1,3,5,4,2`], or some other set.

The only thing important, is the sum that is calculated and nothing else, as long as it matches the input of dices.

*For example:*

- If the `target` is `12` and a list of numbers is `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]` then return value should be `36`.
- If we receive a list of numbers `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]` and a `target` is should be `12` (`5+1+6=12` and also `5+4+3=12`, however, numbers can only be used once and not reused, therefore only one of the combinations can contribute the result).

---

Below is a method, which gives the occurrences of a dice.

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, Integer> countOccurrences(List<Integer> numbers){
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        
    int i = 0;
    for(int n: numbers) {
        if(map.containsKey(n)) {
            i = map.get(n);
            map.put(n, ++i);
        }
        else
            map.put(n, 1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

**Results:**

```
Occurrences: {1=2, 2=1, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1}
```

---

**Sample code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sum(combinationSum(List.of(1, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6), 12)));
    System.out.println(combinationSum(List.of(1, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6), 12));
    System.out.println(combinationSum(List.of(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6), 6));
}

public static int sum(List<List<Integer>> numbers)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(n < numbers.size()){
        sum += numbers.get(n).stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        ++n;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(List<Integer> candidates, int target) {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> ds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    findCombinations(res, ds, target, candidates, 0);
    return res;
}

private static void findCombinations(List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> ds, int target, List<Integer> arr, int index ){
    if(target == 0){res.add(new ArrayList<>(ds));  return;}
    
    for(int i= index ; i<arr.size(); i++){
            if(i>index && arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)) continue;
            if(arr.get(i) > target) break;
            ds.add(arr.get(i));
            findCombinations( res, ds, target-arr.get(i) , arr, i+1);
            ds.remove(ds.size()-1 );
    }
}
```

**Produces:**

```
24
[[1, 6, 5], [1, 5, 6], [3, 3, 6], [3, 3, 6], [6, 6]]
[[1, 1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [1, 5], [6]]
```

**Live running:** https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sHY

Comment: Also classically known as the knapsack problem.

Comment: So you want to find out whether it's possible or not to construct the target sum from the given numbers *recursively*, using any of the number in the list not more than once, correct?

Comment: Maybe return type might be `boolean`, what's the point of returning the same number to the caller?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, why `boolean` ?

Comment: Can you answer the first question (where I'm asking whether my understanding of the problem is correct) ?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, please see the entire post. I just added more, see the last code snippet here as well. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't answer my question? You need to find out whether it's possible to obtain the target sum from the given numbers? Right?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, for example, given this list: `[1,3,2,2,6,5]` find out with which numbers, you can sum together to construct target value. Is it possible to do it more than once? If, target= **12**, then yes, **3+2+2+5=12** but so will **1+5+6**, however, if we use the numbers to sum a target value, we cannot reuse the same numbers. Meaning that, if **3+2+2+5=12** these match and are used, we are left with `[1,6]` and if these two do not sum to the target then we are **DONE**.

Comment: `Is it possible to do it more than once? ` - there's no mention of this requirement in your question. And this requirement is **important**, it should be added to to the question: your current problem statement is vague: *the sum of numbers that makes up the target. And then removes the rest if there aren't anymore*

Comment: `do not sum to the target then we are DONE.` - and what should be the return `value` (non of the examples shows what should be returned), number of combinations that add up to the target sum?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, every detailed information is in the post here. The examples there highlight the problem as a whole. If, `[,3,2,2,6,6,5]` sort = `[2,2,3,5,6,6]` and sum up the firs possible sum till we reach the target, **2+2+3+5** = 12, and then we are left with remainders which we need to test again, in this context `[6,6]` also produce target value **12** therefore, we add this sum to the sums and hence = 12 + 12 = 24.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, please, please. > "what should be the return value", please see the latest version, **New version** above which adds up the sums in an ArrayList and then returns the sum();

Comment: `if(numbers.size() == 0) {
            sums.add(sum);
            return sums.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        }`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, I've added a **PROBLEM** description now to further explain the issue.

Comment: I've read it. I'll try again, please correct me if I'm getting you wrong. Let's say the target is `12` and it's impossible to sum up the given numbers even once to obtain `12` the return value should be `0`. If only one unique combination (without reuse of numbers) gives `12`, then the return value should be `12`. If there are two such unique combinations, then the return value would be `24`. And so on. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, **EXACTLY**, and one combination can only be used once.

Comment: See the [*demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sKM) with your new code. Numbers: `[6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3]`, target `3`. The result should be `6`.  But method `findCombinations()` fail to find any combinations because of the condition `if(arr.get(i) > target) break;`

Comment: The line `if(i>index && arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)) continue;` is suspicious  - why should we prohibit the the same value to be added to the combination? And BTW `arr.get(i) == arr.get(i-1)` is not a correct way to compare instances `Integer` (always use `equals()` to compare objects). I think this line isn't helpful here, consider removing it. In regard to `if(arr.get(i) > target) break; - change it to `continue`.

Comment: The logic in the method `sum()` is not viable. It neither checks anyhow whether the next combination overlap with previously encountered combinations, no verifies if the current sum is optimal (or there are better options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

In order to find the maximum possible score of the list, we maximize the number of *non-overlapping combinations* that we can construct from it.

For we need to take the following steps:

- Find all the possible *combinations* which produce the `target` sum. We can **not** reject any combinations on the fly, because we can't know in advance which of them can be used in the optimal solution. For instance, if `target` is `6` and a list of number is `[3,3,2,2,1,1]`, there will be the following combinations: `[3,3]`, `[2,2,1,1]` and `[3,2,1]` appear two times. If we pick `[3,3]`, which is the shortest combination, we will not be able to construct any combinations and resulting score will be wrong (`6`). Instead, we need to choose two combinations `[3,2,1]` which well give the result `12`. That proves that we can't rely on the combination size, we need to explore all the combinations and then choose the optimal set of combinations.
- Generate all possible groups of combinations that fit to the given list of numbers and find a group having the maximum number of combinations in it.

In the code below both steps are implemented recursively.

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sKN)

*Expalanation:*

The enty point, this method that kicks in the process.

```
public static int sumRecursively(List<Integer> numbers, int target) {
    Deque<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayDeque<>();
    generateCombinations(numbers, combinations, new ArrayList<>(), target);
    
    return processCombinations(combinations, numbers, target);
}
```

**Step 1**. Generating all the *combinations*.

Recursive method responsible for generating the set of combinations (implemented as `void` to avoid wrapping a combination with an additional collection and then throwing this wrapper away):

```
private static void generateCombinations(List<Integer> numbers,
                                         Queue<List<Integer>> combinations,
                                         List<Integer> combination,
                                         int currentSum) {
    
    if (currentSum == 0) { // base case - a combination has been found
        combinations.add(combination);
        return;
    }        
    // recursive case        
    for (Integer next : numbers) { // loop is need only to discard the elements that exceed the currentSum - pay attention to the condition below and break clause at the end of the loop (we will bread out of the loop after the first encountered element that fits to the current sum)
        
        if (next > currentSum) continue;
        
        List<Integer> newNumbers = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
        newNumbers.remove(next);
        // there two opportunities for each number: use it, or ignore it
        // add next number
        List<Integer> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(combination);
        newCombination.add(next);
        getCombinations(newNumbers, combinations, newCombination, currentSum - next);
        // ignore next number
        getCombinations(newNumbers, combinations, new ArrayList<>(combination), currentSum);
        
        break;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**. Generating the *groups of combinations*.

Method below is responsible choosing the group that fits to the given list (i.e. we can construct all the combinations in the group from list elements) and has the maximum number of combinations in it.

All the functionality related to the procissing the the group of combinations (which represents a `List<List<Integer>>`) is incapsulated in a class `CombinationGroup` to make the code cleaner.

```
public static int processCombinations(Deque<List<Integer>> combinations,
                                      List<Integer> numbers,
                                      int target) {
    
    List<CombinationGroup> combinationGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    generateGroups(combinationGroups, combinations, new CombinationGroup(numbers.size()));
    
    return combinationGroups.stream()
        .filter(group -> group.canConstruct(numbers))
        .mapToInt(group -> group.getCombCount() * target)
        .max()
        .orElse(0);
}
```

The following method is responsible for creating the all possible groups of previosly descovered combinations. There's also a small optimization: total number of elements in each group should not exceed the number of elements in the source list:

```
public static void generateGroups(List<CombinationGroup> groups,
                                  Deque<List<Integer>> combinations,
                                  CombinationGroup group) {
    
    if (combinations.isEmpty()) {
        groups.add(group);
        return;
    }
    
    Deque<List<Integer>> combinationsCopy = new ArrayDeque<>(combinations);
    List<Integer> comb = null;
    while (!combinationsCopy.isEmpty() && (comb == null || !group.canAdd(comb))) {
        comb = combinationsCopy.removeLast();
    }
    // adding the combination
    if (comb != null) {
        CombinationGroup groupWithNewComb = group.copy();
        groupWithNewComb.addCombination(comb);
        generateGroups(groups, combinationsCopy, groupWithNewComb);
    }
    // ignoring the combination
    generateGroups(groups, combinationsCopy, group);
}
```

Class `CombinationGroup` used in the methods above:

```
public class CombinationGroup {
    private List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    private int combCount; // number of combinations
    private int size;      // total number of elements in the list of combinations
    private int sizeLimit;
    
    public CombinationGroup(int sizeLimit) {
        this.sizeLimit = sizeLimit;
    }
    
    public boolean canAdd(List<Integer> combination) {
        return size + combination.size() <= sizeLimit;
    }
    
    public boolean addCombination(List<Integer> combination) {
        if (!canAdd(combination)) return false;
        
        combinations.add(combination);
        size += combination.size();
        combCount++;
        return true;
    }
    
    public CombinationGroup copy() {
        CombinationGroup copy = new CombinationGroup(this.sizeLimit);
        for (List<Integer> comb : combinations) {
            copy.addCombination(comb);
        }
        return copy;
    }
    
    public boolean canConstruct(List<Integer> numbers) {
        if (numbers.size() < size) return false;
        
        Map<Integer, Long> frequencyByValueNumb = getFrequencies(numbers.stream());
        Map<Integer, Long> frequencyByValueComb = getFrequencies();
        
        return frequencyByValueNumb.keySet().stream() // each element that prent this CombinationGroup appears in the given list of numbers appears at least the same number of times - that means we construct all these combinations from the given list
            .allMatch(key -> frequencyByValueNumb.get(key) >= frequencyByValueComb.getOrDefault(key, 0L));
    }
    
    public Map<Integer, Long> getFrequencies() {
        return getFrequencies(combinations.stream().flatMap(List::stream));
    }
    
    public Map<Integer, Long> getFrequencies(Stream<Integer> stream) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting()
        ));
    }

    public int getCombCount() {
        return combCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CombinationGroup{" +
            "combinations=" + combinations +
            '}';
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumRecursively(List.of(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6), 12));
    System.out.println(sumRecursively(List.of(1, 3, 3, 6, 5), 12));
    System.out.println(sumRecursively(List.of(1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6), 6));
}
```

*Output:*

```
24
12
18
```

---

#### Simplified algorithm

###### (doesn't maximizes the number of combinations)

In order to ensure that all the elements in each combination are unique, we to **track** indices that have been already used. I.e. each time we find a combination which sums up to the target number, we should prohibit the usage of elements that have been used in this combination, but not earlier (because there can be many combinations which are not able to produce the target, and therefore any element should eligible to be used until we didn't construct a complete combination that gives the target using this element).

To track the elements that are taken, we need an object that would be visible in every recursive branch. And we are already passing a list of numbers while making every recursive call, what if we would modify it each time we found a combination that produces the target number by removing the elements that have been use in this combination? If we took this road after the first combination, thing would become complicated because we will not be able to rely on the indices (*because they can change in an unpredictable way*) while constructing a single combination - it's crucial to ensure that each element that belongs to a particular combination is used only once withing a combination. Since values of elements might be identical, we should use the iteration order to construct each combination properly, but each removal of elements would create a mess. So, is there a better way?

We can maintain an array of `boolean` values, each element is this array would indicate whether a number at a particular index already belongs to a combination that gives the target or not.

Instead of clattering the recursive method with the code that manipulates with this `boolean` array, I've encapsulated it within a class with simple and self-explanatory methods, and `sumRecursively()` makes use of an instance of this class.

```
public class CombinationTracker {
    private boolean[] isUsed;
    
    public CombinationTracker(int size) {
        this.isUsed = new boolean[size];
    }
    
    public boolean indexIsUsed(int ind) {
        return isUsed[ind];
    }
    
    public boolean allNotUsed(List<Integer> indices) {
//            return indices.stream().noneMatch(i -> isUsed[i]); // this line does the same as the loop below
        
        boolean result = true;
        for (int idx: indices) {
            if (isUsed[idx]) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public void setIsUsed(List<Integer> indices) {
        for (int ind: indices)
            setIsUsed(ind);
    }
    
    public void setIsUsed(int ind) {
        isUsed[ind] = true;
    }
}
```

Using this approach, we are able to construct combinations from numbers that are not used yet, and iterate over the list of numbers starting from a particular position by passing the index while making a recursive call.  We can be sure that any of the elements that reside prier to the current position would not be added to the current combination.

Now, a quick recap on *recursion*.

Every recursive implementation consists of two parts:

- **Base case** - that represents an edge-case (*or a set of edge-cases*) for which the outcome is known in advance. For this problem, there are **two** edge-cases:

  - we've managed to find a combination that gives the target number, i.e. `currentSum == target`, and the result would be equal to `target`;
  - the end of the list is reached (and the combination doesn't result to the target), the result would be `0` (this edge-case resolves automatically by termination condition of the `for` loop in the *recursive case*, and therefore no need to treat it separately).
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where recursive calls are made and where the main logic resides. In the *recursive case* we're iterating over the list of numbers and at each iteration step (*if the index is not yet used*) we are making *one* or *two* recursive calls depending on a value of the current element (*depending whether we exceed the target or not*). In the general, we have two opportunities: either take the current element, or ignore it. The results of these recursive calls would be added together and produce the return value of the *recursive case*.

Since we need a couple of additional parameters, it's a good practice to create an auxiliary overloaded method (*that will be used in the client code*) which expects *only* a list of numbers and a target value and delegates the actual work to the recursive method.

That's how it might look like.

```
public static int sumRecursively(List<Integer> numbers, int target) {
    
    return sumRecursively(new ArrayList<>(numbers),
                          new ArrayList<>(),
                          new CombinationTracker(numbers.size()),
                          0, 0, target);
}
```

The actual recursive method:

```
private static int sumRecursively(List<Integer> numbers,
                                  List<Integer> combination,
                                  CombinationTracker tracker,
                                  int currentIndex,
                                  int currentSum, int target) {
    
    if (currentSum == target && tracker.allNotUsed(combination)) { // base case - a combination has been found
        tracker.setIsUsed(combination);
        return target;
    }
    
    // recursive case
    int result = 0;
    
    for (int i = currentIndex; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

        int next = numbers.get(i);

        if (tracker.indexIsUsed(i)) continue;
        if (currentSum + next > target) continue;
        // there are two opportunities for each number: either use next number, or ignore it
        // add next number
        if (next + currentSum <= target) {
            List<Integer> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(combination);
            newCombination.add(i);
            result += sumRecursively(numbers, newCombination, tracker, i + 1, currentSum + next, target);
        }
        // ignore next number
        result += sumRecursively(numbers, new ArrayList<>(combination), tracker, i + 1, currentSum, target);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sumRecursively(List.of(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6), 12));
    System.out.println(sumRecursively(List.of(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), 12));
}
```

*Output:*

```
12
36
```

Comment: Hi, the following does not work: `{1,2,1,4,5,6}` **how come?**

Comment: @AlixBlaine What is the target number?

Comment: Alexander, it is **6**, which means, `4+2 = 6, 5+1 = 6, and 6` = **18**, remaining `{1,2}`

Comment: @AlixBlaine I see, that's because combinations `[1,1,4]`, `[2,4]` and `[1,5]` overlap. When we are picking the first one, then we are unable to choose the others. To maximize the total can't reject combinations on the fly, instead we need to generate all of them and find the maximum number of non-overlapping combinations. I'll improve the solution.

Comment: Alexander, I am working on a separate solution, to deal with the following range: `3, 4, 5, 6,` meaning, that if, the target is one of these, then, remove all matching numbers of the target into a separate list, e.g., all `6` and then deal with the reminders. If, the target exceeds 6, e.g. 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 <-- 12 is the maximum btw, then a recursive approach might be needed. I am thinking of using `Stack<Integer>`. Two separates stacks. One contaning all of the numbers, and the other one containing the tested. With `Stack` you just `pop()` the next number or, `Queue` LIFO/FIFO approaches.

Comment: @AlixBlaine I've already found a solution (see the code at the very beginning). More detailed explanation will be added soon.

Comment: @AlixBlaine Have a look at the updated answer, and please give your feedback. The code produces correct results, and both major steps (generating the combinations and combining them into groups) are implemented *recursively* as required.

Comment: Does not work, as expected. I am sorry.

Comment: @AlixBlaine Which test case fails? Maybe you can provide a link to verify the code if it's a kind of online code-challenge?

Comment: Alexander, please see my latest code. If you can figure out a way, to select from the combinations best combos that are unique and match expected sum, let me know.

Comment: @AlixBlaine The key point is that you can't know in advance to choose without looking at all of them. If two combinations interfere (have one or more common numbers) you can say which of them is more useful looking at them in isolation. Even if combination is shorter than other it might seem it has fewer chances to overlap and leaves more intact numbers it has no upper hand over other combinations (*see explanation in the answer*). The only case when we can tell that a combination is `100%` good to go is when it consists of a single number, its guaranteed not interfere with other combinations.

Comment: @AlixBlaine `[1,6,5]` has no advantage over `[3,3,6]` it doesn't matter which one to choose. But we can tell it after we have checked that there's no more opportunities. In general there's no single bunch of the *best combos*, there could be multiple **different** optimal groups of combinations that allow to maximize the score. To find these optimal combinations we need to construct a set of "combinations of combinations", meaning need to generate *groups of combinations* and then operate with groups (again see the updated part of the answer, it describes how to create and analyze the groups).

Comment: What do you think of, if, I mention: **Intersect** and **Union** ?

Comment: *Intersect and Union* - You mean *Intersection* and *Union* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation ) ? We need a *union* of combinations. *Intersection* appear when two or more combinations compete for the same number (or numbers).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Would be good to do with my code which is faster.

Comment: @AlixBlaine I gave you feedback on your solution and kindly ask you again to provide feedback on mine. If it's broken, please show it. It's **not** slower anyhow. The worse case time complexity for generating all combinations that sum up to the target (denoted as **step 1** in my answer) is quadratic, it's impossible to reduce it and you didn't implemented this part correctly. We can't compare any further because your solution completely lucks the logic that I've described as a **step 2** in my answer.

Comment: @AlixBlaine If something in the explanation I've provided is unclear that's that's fine, I can try to rephrase it, just point at the **specific place** which isn't clear. But it's impossible to reiterate everything.

Comment: @AlixBlaine `Does not work, as expected.` - If it's indeed not working, can you please give me a proof?

Comment: **Yes**, does not work, explain this, `The score of [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]    for target 12 is: 12`, `6+6 6+6 6+6 = 36`, not *12*.

Comment: @AlixBlaine You're wrong - it **does work**, the code returns `36` as expected [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sKB). It's precisely the **same** that I've posted in the answer.

Comment: I just ran your code again, `The score of [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]    for target 12 is: 24` anyway. I have updated everything. Please look at the information in this post.

Comment: @AlixBlaine Check the link - it **does work**, the code returns `36` as expected [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sKB). It's precisely the **same** that I've posted in the answer.

Comment: Please see my EDIT.

Comment: @AlixBlaine Don't ignore the question. Did you check the link? If the code is broken, give me the proof.

Comment: @AlixBlaine In programming, everything can be measured, you can tell that something isn't working or is slower without any reason. Talk is chip! There's no evidence that my code is broken, and don't see any reason. You should explain to me why do you claim that before asking to look at your code, which is indeed broken.

Comment: Mate, please relax a little bit. I need to test it further, before, I can answer. Relax.

Comment: @AlixBlaine You've said it yesterday. Did you had the actual reason to state that?

Comment: This does not work, `The score of [4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2] for target 4 is: 12`. Here, 4+4+4+ 2+2=4 => 16

Comment: @AlixBlaine Fixed, there was a bug in one line of code [see the last test case](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sKN), constructor of the `CombinationGroup` was receiving the wrong value as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

UPD.

Got a comment that code "sucks" due to performance issues...

First of all, I do believe you have missed a point the SO community is not a kind of service which solves code interview puzzles, generally speaking, if you came here with a puzzle you already failed, so, such comments are unacceptable.

At second, yes, the code suffers from performance issues just because it is a naive bruteforce solution - I had spent on it about 15 minutes (for example, figuring out all possible combinations with target sum has O(2^N) complexity, if it does not match performance expectations that means any code based on such idea has poor performance). BTW, if you had expectations about the performance you was need to:

- provide correct input constraints (saying `there is 6 numbers` is not correct)
- provide good testcases instead of saying `code does not work` - that allows us to eliminate bad ideas about algorithm.

Some idea:

it seems that we do not need to compute all possible combinations with target sum, because singletons are always preferable over N-lets, pairs are either the same or do not influence on the result or interchangeable with N-lets (e.g. in case of [2,2,8,10,10] we would prefer to eliminate pairs first), but whether it is true for higher N's completely unclear - it is better to have some testcases.

---

Not sure I properly understand the problem, but I believe the solution is following:

```java
public class TargetNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(score(new int[]{1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6}, 6));
    }

    public static int score(int[] candidates, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> combinations = getUniqueCombinations(candidates, target);
        Map<Integer, Integer> freqs = new HashMap<>();
        for (int n : candidates) {
            freqs.merge(n, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
        return score(0, combinations, freqs, target);
    }

    public static int score(int offset, List<List<Integer>> combinations, Map<Integer, Integer> freqs, int target) {
        if (offset == combinations.size()) {
            return 0;
        }
        int result = 0;
        List<Integer> comb = combinations.get(offset);
        Map<Integer, Integer> nfreq = reduce(freqs, comb);
        if (nfreq != null) {
            result = Math.max(result, target + score(offset, combinations, nfreq, target));
        }
        result = Math.max(result, score(offset + 1, combinations, freqs, target));
        return result;
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> reduce(Map<Integer, Integer> freqs, List<Integer> comb) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>(freqs);
        for (int n : comb) {
            if (result.merge(n, -1, Integer::sum) < 0) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> getUniqueCombinations(int[] candidates, int target) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(candidates);
        getUniqueCombinations(candidates, target, 0, new ArrayList<>(), result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void getUniqueCombinations(int[] candidates, int target, int index, List<Integer> solution, List<List<Integer>> result) {
        for (int i = index, n = candidates.length; i < n; ) {
            int num = candidates[i];
            if (num > target) {
                break;
            }
            solution.add(num);
            if (num == target) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<>(solution));
            }
            getUniqueCombinations(candidates, target - num, i + 1, solution, result);
            solution.remove(solution.size() - 1);
            while (i < n && num == candidates[i]) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```